# Error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, if-statement, controls

I cannot figure out why I'm getting this compiler error.  I have declared `i` in the for loop, but my control statement doesn't see it.

The error is occurring on this line: `if (mystring[cmd_index][i] == '\\')`

```
/* 
 * Check for the " character in the mystring 
 * and remove the character if it doesn't have the delimiter
 */
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(mystring[cmd_index]); i++) {
    if (mystring[cmd_index][i] == '\\') {
        i++;
    } else
    if (mystring[cmd_index][i] == '"') {
        printf("HELLO");

        if (i != strlen(mystring[cmd_index] - 1)) {
            shiftLeft(mystring[cmd_index], i + 1, 1);
        } else {
            mystring[cmd_index][i] = '\0';
        }
    }
}
```

Edit1: I am using `gcc` version 5.4.0

Edit2: I copied the same code and pasted it right below the original. Then commented out the original. It's compiling now. But when I undo this and use the original code, it won't compile again. Why??

Comment: Which compiler and version of C are you using?

Comment: I'd guess you are using `i` after the loop where it isn't defined.  Please post an MCVE ([MCVE]) and the error message with line number.

Comment: Declare `int i;` before the for-loop and change the for-loop into `for (i = 0; i < strlen(mystring[cmd_index]); i++)`.

Comment: You should try what @hmofrad said.These thing's depend on the compiler ,Program,and c version you are using.For example using  `Turbo c [old c version]` i have to declare variables just after the `main()` but in `code blocks 16.01` I can declare variables any where given syntax is correct

Comment: I have tried what hmofrad says. i is recognized inside the loop, but it will not increment by i++.

Comment: Curious.  Why `int i` instead of `size_t i` to match the type returned by `strlen()`?

Comment: I'm coming from a C++ background, my projects for this class are coded in C. I was unfamiliar with size_t.

Comment: can you update the exact error message that you are receiving?

Comment: I believe problem is about the standard version. Try to compile it with --std=c99. It will allow you to declare variable inside for statement.

Comment: note: `strlen()` returns type `size_t`, not `int`.  so `i` should be declared as `size_t`

Answer (score 1):

Wy wild guess is you have an extra `;` at the end of your original `for` statement, such as this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(mystring[cmd_index]); i++);
{
    ...
```

This would effectively give the `for` loop an empty body and the subsequent block is outside the scope of the `for` loop.

Avoid this kind of mistake by putting the `{` at the end of the `for` line instead of on a separate line.

Comment: I have checked for the ; at the end of the for loop when the error occured. That was not the problem.

Comment: @TommySaechao: can you copy the code for the whole function that causes the problem and reindent it by selecting the whole code and pressing Ctrl-K

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason that you may have this weird issue is that you are changing `i` inside your for-loop also. I skip those increments using `continue;` to let for-loop be consistence. The code below tries to *remove the double quotes* and *preserve the forward slashes*, as I understand from your question.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char mystring[3][10];
    memset(mystring, '\0', sizeof(mystring));

    memcpy(mystring[0], "He\\l\"lo\"", sizeof(mystring[0]));
    memcpy(mystring[1], "cr\\u\"el\"", sizeof(mystring[1]));
    memcpy(mystring[2], "wo\\r\"ld\"", sizeof(mystring[2]));

    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        printf("Before: %s\n", mystring[j]);
        for(i = 0; i < strlen(mystring[j]); i++)
        {
            if(mystring[j][i] == '\\') // Skip Backward slashes
                continue;
            else if(mystring[j][i] == '"') // Remove double quotes
            {  
                for(k = i; k < strlen(mystring[j]); k++)
                    mystring[j][k] = mystring[j][k+1];
            }
        }
        printf("After: %s\n", mystring[j]);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Note that, there is no need to add any specific flag while compiling it using `gcc`.

Comment: *you are changing i inside your for-loop* -> this is true and sloppy but does not explain the OP's problem.

Comment: My first guess was `c99` for-loop convention which I think is not the issue. Also, there might be a problem inside the code having multiple isolated  code blocks using { .. }.

Comment: I checked the edit history: some of the braces were removed in one of the edits, but this is not the cause for the problem. I think the most likely cause is a spurious `;` that the OP did not copy.